# Firebase throws Error: Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

Tags: angular, firebase, google-analytics, crashlytics, angularfire

I've been using `AngularCrashlytics(from @angular/fire)` for a while interestingly since this morning I became unable to get either `build` or `ng serve` which throws error as below.Can someone help me to get rid of this?

[image]

On the `app.module` I've already added `@angular/fire` releated configuration steps as below(taken from https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/analytics/getting-started.md)

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAnalyticsModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/analytics';

imports:[
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.Tools.Firebase)//firebase releated config,
AngularFireAnalyticsModule
]
```

I have configuration mentioned as below, with `ng version` [image]

Dependency versions from package.json

```
"firebase": "^9.14.0",
"@angular/fire": "^7.4.1"
```

**Additional Note** : Already cloned project from scratch many times have tried deleting `node modules` folder and `npm install` besides tried to upgrade both firebase and @angular/fire to the latest versions which didn't fix the issue.

Comment: No idea what is the root cause, but in my project i got the same problem today as well. Yesterday all was working fine, and today i run npm update, and get the error. One thing that my help you, revert the "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1" to "@angular/fire": "7.2.1". I know this is not best solution, but it may help

Comment: I got the same issue today but downgrading @angular/fire to 7.2.1 doesn't fix the issue either.

Comment: Thanks to @Nikola.grancharov 's answer I tried to downgrade @angular/fire to 7.2.1 first all errors disappeared except Can't resolve 'rxfire/auth' in ... . To resolve that I had to install it via npm i rxfire then totally fine

Comment: downgrade to 7.4.1 angular/fire solved for me.  this was with a new demo project created today with ng new and ng add @angular/fire, i did have to delete node_modules and package.lock.json and npm i

Comment: same for [react](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75337593/14047838)

Answer (score 2):

This morning I updated Angular from 15.1.2 to 15.1.3:

[image]

This threw 34 errors, all involving AngularFire:

```
Error: export 'GoogleAuthProvider' (imported as 'GoogleAuthProvider') was not found in '@angular/fire/auth'

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-analytics.js:7:0-47 - Error: Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one
```

I tried using `overrides` in `package.json` but `npm install` refused to run the overrides, throwing `EOVERRIDE` errors. `npm install --force` didn't help.

I fixed it by not using `overrides` but instead changing "^15.0.0" to "15.1.2" and then running `npm install --force`.

I don't understand why `overrides` didn't work. I might ask a question about this.

I'll wait until a new version of AngularFire is released before updating to the latest Angular.

Comment: Thank You! This fixed the issue for me. What does "^" [caret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/14047838) mean in npm dependencies.

Comment: The ^ caret means "and updates in this version." "^15.0.0" will update with "npm update" to 15.0.1, 15.1.0, etc. but not to 16.0.0.

Comment: My question about overrides is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340053/confused-about-overrides-in-package-json/75341354. tl;dr don't use overrides to revert to an older version. Overrides are for managing the dependencies of dependencies.

Comment: I updated Angular to 15.2.0, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue comes from the dependency here:
node_modules/@angular/fire/package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase": "^9.8.0",
```

As stated here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7005#issuecomment-1415807037

Removing the ^ within the version solved it for me.

I did this in my projects package.json to override it:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": ...
  "dependencies": ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },  
  "overrides": {
    "@angular/fire": {
      "firebase": "9.8.0"
    }
  },
```

Then run "npm install" to apply this.

Should be fixed in the next release of "@angular/fire".

Comment: This threw a bunch of errors when I tried it. `ERESOLVE could not resolve` dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In package.json add this code:

```
  "overrides": {
    "@angular/fire": {
      "firebase": "9.8.1"
    }
  }
```

version from fire is:  "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1"
and node 16.14.2 with npm 8.5.0
Delete rm -r node_modules package-lock.json .angular
Only npm not yarn

Answer (score 0):

issue with angular fire
https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-15-firestore-crud/
To get rid of these errors, you must update the tsconfig.json file.

```
 ...
  "compilerOptions": {
 ...
  "skipLibCheck": true.  //add this line!!!!!!!
 },
 ...
```