# in Angular Module @angular/fire not found

Tags: angular, firebase

I have tried the following steps but the issue still persists:

- npm install
- npm i firebase @angular/fire --save
- npm cache clean --force
- Checking all dependencies

My project was working yesterday with the same code. I was working on my data structure and now I am getting a dependency error. I have rolled back all my changes using "git reset --hard" and ran my application, but it doesn't work.

```
{
  "name": "Radimdienst",
  "version": "2.1.1",
  "author": "Muhammed",
  "homepage": "https://radimdienst.de",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.4",
    "@capacitor/android": "^4.6.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.6.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.4.1",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
    "capacitor": "^0.0.3",
    "firebase": "^9.17.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.0.4",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.6.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

this is the error

```
./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-app-check.js:7:0-47 - Error: Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-app-check.js:9:0-200 - Error: Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one
./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:3:0-39 - Error: Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:4:0-70 - Error: Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:5:0-66 - Error: Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:6:0-49 - Error: Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one
```

and this is my npm ls

```
+-- __ngcc_entry_points__.json@ extraneous
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.1.4
+-- @angular/cli@15.1.4
+-- @angular/common@15.1.3
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@15.1.3
+-- @angular/compiler@15.1.3
+-- @angular/core@15.1.3
+-- @angular/fire@7.5.0
+-- @angular/forms@15.1.3
+-- @angular/language-service@15.1.3
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@15.1.3
+-- @angular/platform-browser@15.1.3
+-- @angular/router@15.1.3
+-- @capacitor/android@4.6.2
+-- @capacitor/cli@4.6.1
+-- @capacitor/core@4.6.2
+-- @ionic/angular-toolkit@7.0.0
+-- @ionic/angular@6.5.2
+-- @ionic/pwa-elements@3.1.1
+-- @types/jasmine@4.3.1
+-- @types/jasminewd2@2.0.10
+-- @types/node@18.11.18
+-- capacitor@0.0.3
+-- codelyzer@6.0.2
+-- firebase@9.17.0
+-- jasmine-core@4.5.0
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@7.0.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@3.1.1
+-- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@3.0.3
+-- karma-coverage@2.2.0
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@2.0.0
+-- karma-jasmine@5.1.0
+-- karma@6.4.1
+-- pdfmake@0.2.7
+-- protractor@7.0.0
+-- rxjs@7.8.0
+-- ts-node@10.9.1
+-- tslib@2.5.0
+-- tslint@6.1.3
+-- typescript@4.8.4
`-- zone.js@0.12.0
```

Comment: Thank's very much i downgrade th @angular/fire to ''7.4.1" and it works agaain. Do u have any idea, why i have this issue. my project worked with @angular/fire 7.5.0 yesterday.