# React Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, create-react-app

I'm working on a React project setup using `node 16.17.0`, Create React App `"react-scripts": "^5.0.0"` with `"react": "^17.0.2"`
Everything was working fine until this morning. When I try to `npm run start` or `npm run build`, it gives me the below error. The `npm install` works fine showing no errors.

The errors that I am getting are:

```
ERROR in ./src/services/auth/firebase/firebase.js 3:0-45
Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

ERROR in ./src/services/auth/firebase/firebase.js 4:0-40
Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

ERROR in ./src/app/pages/payout/PayoutOpen.js 5:0-39
Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-query-firebase/auth/dist/bundle.es.js 3:0-78
Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-query-firebase/auth/dist/bundle.es.js 4:0-720
Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one
```

This is how my `firebase.js` file looks like:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebase = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "********",
    authDomain: "*******",
    projectId: "*********",
    storageBucket: "**********",
    messagingSenderId: "***************",
    appId: "****************",
    measurementId: "*************"
});

export const auth = getAuth(firebase);
```

I tried to remove `node_modules` folder, remove `package-lock.json` file, clear npm cache but nothing works. I also tried to install using yarn but it shows the same error.

Comment: Probably related [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7005).

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, Thank you @SergeySosunov

Comment: Decided to answer normally to your question due to probably there will be other similar questions, so we will be able to mark them as duplicate of yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fresh issue as per 03 Feb 2023, happens due to `firebase v9.17.0`.

Fix:

1. npm un firebase
2. npm i firebase@9.16.0

Or:

1. modify package.json, use `"firebase": "9.16.0"` instead of `"firebase": "^9.16.0"`.
2. run `npm i` or `yarn`.

Related github issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7005