# Confused about `overrides` in `package.json`

Tags: package.json

Why does `overrides` not work:

```js
 {
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "15.1.2",
        "@angular/common": "15.1.2",
        ...
    },
    "overrides": {
        "@angular/animations": "15.1.2",
 
    }
  }
```

when this works:

```js
 {
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "15.1.2",
        "@angular/cdk": "15.1.2",
        "@angular/common": "15.1.2",
        ...
    }
 }
```

Is my override telling `package.json` to set `"@angular/animations"` to `15.1.2`?

The former throws an `EOVERRIDE` error when I run `npm install` or `npm install --force`:

```
npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE
npm ERR! Override for @angular/animations@^15.0.0 conflicts with direct dependency
```

The [overrides documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) says this:

> You may not set an override for a package that you directly depend on
> unless both the dependency and the override itself share the exact
> same spec. To make this limitation easier to deal with, overrides may
> also be defined as a reference to a spec for a direct dependency by
> prefixing the name of the package you wish the version to match with a
> $.

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    // BAD, will throw an EOVERRIDE error
    // "foo": "^2.0.0"
    // GOOD, specs match so override is allowed
    // "foo": "^1.0.0"
    // BEST, the override is defined as a reference to the dependency
    "foo": "$foo",
    // the referenced package does not need to match the overridden one
    "bar": "$foo"
  }
}
```

Is the documentation saying that

- BAD: The override can't be newer than the dependency.
- GOOD: The override can be the same as the dependency. This what I'm doing.
- BEST: I don't understand what this.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of *overrides* is to manage **dependencies of your dependencies**.

So if you would like to override one of your package which is in your direct deps (@angular/animations is in your direct deps) then there are 2 options:

1)

```js
 {
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    },
    "overrides": {
        "@angular/animations": "$@angular/animations",
 
    }
  }
```

**All** @angular/animations packages in your deps tree will be replaced to ^15.0.0, but there is limitation you mentioned (*override* must contain the same version as *dependencies* contains).

2)

```js
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    },
    "overrides": {
        "some_package":{"@angular/animations": "any version"},
    }
}
```

You may use nested syntax (replace dep version for a specific package) and then there is not limitation for the same version.

About 'BEST' option from the docs. You may use prefix $ plus just name of the package and then you will avoid yourself to update version inside *override* field each time when version inside *dependencies* will be updated.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say what I'm trying to do. I updated from 15.1.2 to 15.1.3 and a dependency crashed this. I need to revert back to 15.1.2. That's easy enough, I changed ^15.0.0 to 15.1.2 and ran "npm install --force". Can I do this using overrides?

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe if you are talking about your direct dependency then I would propose to fix version to 15.1.2 and do not use overrides field. Overrides makes sense to use if you wanna change version dep of your dep, coz you do not own theirs package.jsons.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood what overrides are for. I've never seen them before.